# Need to create GUI interface in Cent OS which is located in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, gui, centos-5

I am in need to install GUI of Cent OS (5.8-final) in Windows XP.

I have **installed Cent OS 5.8-final on Windows XP using VMPlayer**. And Finally it has been done.

**How can I create a GUI Interface in Cent OS ?**

I googled and **I got a clue that using CNTLM it is possible to do** !!!

But I didn't find any exact tutorials to work it..

Finally I am here for solutions from SuperUsers :-)

Any suggestions or solutions will be grateful and thankful..

Comment: I'm afraid its a little hard to work out what you are trying to do. Are you trying to run a GUI in a centos VM ? Run gnome from centos inside a windows session?

Comment: If you don't have a GUI Interface when you load your Cent OS virtual machine then you didn't install it.  I would simply install the operating system again and install the user interface when given the option to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like either CentOS doesn't boot into runlevel 5 or X server packages are missing (or maybe simply VMware tools aren't installed?)

**Install VMware tools:**

If not yet done, install VMware tools on your CentOS. Check this: http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/howto/centos-5-vmware-tools-install.html.

**Check runlevel 5:**

Log in to CentOS as root and run `runlevel`. If it shows something like:

```
N 3
```

you are running in multiuser, CLI mode. Run `telinit 5`. If nothing happens (that is, no GUI appears) the X server may not be installed.

**Install X server:**

Check this post "Can I add X to my server after install? or I installed from the Server ISO and it didn't install X, how do I install X?": http://www.centos.org/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=50.

Comment: @@jaume: while tryin to run the commands I am getting error. Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base. What to do with this...

Comment: Probably the easiest thing, if you haven't done anything useful with CentOS yet, is to reinstall it and pay attention to install package groups "X Window System" and "GNOME Desktop Environment". (Check this link please: (http://kamranagayev.com/2009/01/05/installing-centos-on-vmware-step-by-step/).) Is this feasible?